# SELECT all contacts (friends) of a user

Tags: mysql, database, select, contacts

I have the following database:
[image: Database Diagram]

user_id and contact_id from Contacts table are PK and FK to the user_id field in the Users table. How can i select all contacts (or friends) of a specific user including the number of contacts of all contacts of this user. I tried different SELECT queries but either the number of contacts is incorrect or the contact_status is printed wrong. I use COUNT() as a function to print the number of contacts. I use this query but the contact_status is printed wrong:

```
SELECT COUNT(Contacts.contact_id), Users.user_id, Users.user_name, Users.name,     Users.user_picture, Users.mood_message, Users.phone_number, Users.email, Users.country,   Users.city, Users.website, Users.birth_date, Users.gender, Users.language, Users.about_me, Users.online_status, Users.privacy, Contacts.contact_status 
FROM Contacts JOIN Users ON Contacts.contact_id = Users.user_id 
WHERE Users.user_name IN ( 
      SELECT Users.user_name 
      FROM Users 
      WHERE Users.user_id IN ( 
            SELECT Contacts.contact_id 
            FROM Contacts 
            WHERE Contacts.user_id = 12 
)
)
GROUP BY Users.user_name;
```

Users Table:

user_id,      user_name,     ...
12  John          ...
13           Matt          ...
14           Jack          ...

Contacts Table:

user_id,     contact_status,     contact_id
12                  1              13
13                  1              12
12                  2              14

If i want to print all Contacts of John the result should consist:

COUNT(Contacts.contacts_id),     Users.user_name,     Users. ... ,    Contacts.contact_status
            1                         Matt             ...                     1
            0                         Jack             ...                     2

The above query prints 1, 1 as a contact_status instead of 1, 2.

Can you help me with this query? Thanks in advance.

Comment: the best action you do to make your question more clearer is to include sample records with desired result in it `:D`

Answer (score 0):

If I understood what's your goal, this should work:

```
SELECT c.contact_status, cc.contactCount, u.*
FROM Contacts c JOIN Users u ON (c.contact_id = u.user_id)
JOIN (
    SELECT user_id, COUNT(1) contactCount FROM Contacts
    GROUP BY user_id
) cc ON (c.user_id = cc.user_id)
WHERE c.user_id = 12
```

Answer (score 0):

I hope I understand ur requirements, but its much simpler to use a subquery, like so:

```
SELECT 
    u.* -- Whatever fields you need
    ,(
           select count(*) from Contacts c
           where c.contactid = co.userid -- refers to outer record
     ) as contact_count
FROM
Users u Inner Join Contacts co
      on co.UserId = u.UserId
WHERE
      U.UserId = 12
```

Comment: Actually I want to SELECT all contacts of a user with ID = 12 including the number of the contacts of each contact of the user with ID = 12. Like in Skype when you open somebody's profile from your contact list you can see how many contacts he has.